# Field extension of a vector space

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, tensors

If $V$ is a vector space over the field $k$, and $K$ is a field extension of $k$, then $(V)_K$ over $K$ is a vector space. How this new vector space is constructed? and how  are the linear transformations defined?

Comment: It is not quite clear what you mean to ask. Exactly what your wrote is not correct as far as I can see. Take for example, $k$ the reals $K$ the complex numbers and $V$ the real numbers. According to what you wrote now the reals should be a vector space over the complex numbers. This is not the case. Either you mean it the other way a $K$ vector space is also a $k$ vecor space, or you do not ask about $V$ itself but rather a modification of $V$.

Comment: @quid in case of $\mathbf R$ we have complexification of real vector spaces but I dot know in general how it is done.

Comment: Okay. But the complexification of $V$ is not the same as $V$ but it is now clearer what you want.

Comment: Thanks for the edit. A brief answer is it is $K \otimes_k V$. Also see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extension_of_scalars

Comment: @quid thanks for the link.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This new space is constructed using the tensor product.  $V_K = K \otimes_k V$.  That means $V_K$ is spanned by symbols of the form $a \otimes v$ where $v \in V$ and $a \in k$.  The scalar multiplication by elements of $K$ is done by multiplying into the left factor
$$b(a \otimes v) = (ba) \otimes v.$$
When manipulating these symbols you are also allowed to cross elements of $k$ over the tensor symbol so
$$(ab) \otimes v = a \otimes bv$$
(but only when $b \in k$!!  If $b \in K \setminus k$ then it can't cross!).  And finally addition can come out of either factor
$$(a + b) \otimes v = a \otimes v + b \otimes v \qquad \text{and} \qquad a \otimes (v + w) = a \otimes v + b\otimes w.$$
Note that these rules are not enough to combine every sum into an element of the form $a \otimes v$.  Guys in that form are called *simple tensors* and in general you get all the elements of $V_K$ by taking sums of simple tensors, just the simple tensors alone doesn't cut it.

If $\{v_1, \ldots, v_n\}$ is a basis for $V$ as a $k$-vector space then $\{1 \otimes v_1, \ldots, 1 \otimes v_n\}$ is a basis for $V_K$ as a $K$-vector space.  Linear transformations of $V_K$ are defined just as they are for any vector space and are uniquely determined (as always) by where they send a basis.